Webcam stopped working after upgrading to Windows 11
My Canyon C2N webcam was working fine in Windows 10 N, but after "upgrade" to 11 N it stopped working. When I went to https://webcamtests.com/ I was told that it was "blocked or used by different app". I scoured process explorer (nothing using webcam there), re-applied all permissions, restarted everything, changed USB ports...
What am I missing?

When I opened Camera desktop app, I was told I was missing Media feature pack. I found the official link, but the Settings > Apps > Optional features path was wrong. I used the search bar in settings to look for Optional features, and found it. There I installed the Media feature pack, restarted, and camera was working again.

Do note, the Media Feature Pack needs to be installed every time you install an upgrade or newer version of Windows, due to the fact that you chosen a Windows N version. This is also why before installing this, you could not play some youtube videos or audio on soundcloud, assuming you tried that. Also, you need a Media Feature Pack specifically for that newer version of Windows. you may want to consider reinstalling to a non N version of windows.
